# Как использовать микрофон в 2 потока?

Tags: android

Привет, друзья!
Я делаю приложение с распознаванием голоса и выводом его в отдельный TextView.
Для визуализации данного процесса я использую [этот пример реализации](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-waveform-sample). На выходе мы имеем примерно такую визуализацию голоса - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализовано это таким образом :

```
// The sampling rate for the audio recorder.
private static final int SAMPLING_RATE = 44100;

private WaveformView mWaveformView;

private RecordingThread mRecordingThread;
private int mBufferSize;
private short[] mAudioBuffer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_waveform);

    mWaveformView = (WaveformView) findViewById(R.id.waveform_view);

    // Compute the minimum required audio buffer size and allocate the buffer.
    mBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLING_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mAudioBuffer = new short[mBufferSize / 2];

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mRecordingThread = new RecordingThread();
    mRecordingThread.start();
}
```

Ну и сам фоновый поток для записи :

```
/**
 * A background thread that receives audio from the microphone and sends it to the waveform
 * visualizing view.
 */
private class RecordingThread extends Thread {

    private boolean mShouldContinue = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);

        AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLING_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, mBufferSize);
        record.startRecording();

        while (shouldContinue()) {
            record.read(mAudioBuffer, 0, mBufferSize / 2);
            mWaveformView.updateAudioData(mAudioBuffer);
            updateDecibelLevel();
        }

        record.stop();
        record.release();
    }

    /**
     * Gets a value indicating whether the thread should continue running.
     *
     * @return true if the thread should continue running or false if it should stop
     */
    private synchronized boolean shouldContinue() {
        return mShouldContinue;
    }

    /** Notifies the thread that it should stop running at the next opportunity. */
    public synchronized void stopRunning() {
        mShouldContinue = false;
    }
```

**Реализация Speech Recognition делается стандартным методом поэтому я думаю сюда ее можно не вносить...**

> Суть вопроса

Когда я запускаю программу работает или визуализатор или recognition, как мне запустить и то и другое одновременно?

Comment: В `RecognitionListener` есть `onBufferReceived()`. Получать данные с него вместо своего  AudioRecord не получится?

Comment: @lsillarionov я пытался, мне нужен short масив а там byte  ну я переделал, но всеравно, голосовой ввод работает а визаулизация нет.

Comment: Похоже, что кто первый захватит микрофон, тот и слушает. я бы отказался от RecordingThread и рисовал данные из буфера, что RecognitionListener вернет, как @lsillarionov пишет.